# How to move view depends on content in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 1 imageview and right side of image, two different textview.1st textview content may grow depents on server text.so 2nd textview should move under that accordingly.Under this whole 3 i have one more textview occupies whole width and it should move accordingly based on above textviews.

Comment: pls post any sort of snap to understand clearly

Comment: 1st textview grow depends on server..databased on that i need to move time text and content review..

Comment: We inflate view in custom listview.same here you can create custom view having two textview above another and aligned right to image by this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/.

Comment: refer above link and you would be able to create the desired layout by doing so.

Comment: i know that.how can i make text to move depends on content.i dnt want specify margintop

Comment: no need to give margintop,instead take relative layout assign layout_below to the textview2 which will place under textview1

Comment: This will always place text2 under text1 rather than giving margintop to it,which will ruin on screen size change

Answer (score 0):

We inflate view in custom listview.same here you can create custom view having two textview above another and aligned right to image by [CustomListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B) example.

Here you can take a relative layout and assign align_below to the textview2 which will place under textview1.This will always place text2 under text1 rather than giving margintop to it,which will ruin on screen size change